# PreparedStatement not putting arguments

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am having problems running this code using PreparedStatement on my MySQL server. It has been doing np before, when I had a standart Statement included. Mind: this is a test program, I am only learning this stuff. The code is:

```
PreparedStatement st = null;
try {
    int id = registry.newID("ID");
    if (id == 0) {
        out.println("Failed to generate a new ID. Terminating dialogue.");
        return;
    }
    String insert = "INSERT INTO registry (ID, NAME, SURNAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH, CITY, STREET) " 
        + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
    st = registry.getConn().prepareStatement(insert);
    st.setInt(1, id);
    st.setString(2, name);
    st.setString(3, surname);
    st.setDate(4, date);
    st.setString(5, city);
    st.setString(6, street);
    st.executeUpdate(insert);
    registry.getConn().commit();
    out.println("Added. Add a number? [y/n] ");
    char choice = in.next().charAt(0);
    if (choice == 'y') {
        addNumber(id, registry);
    }
    st.close();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    out.println("SQL Exception: " + ex);
}
```

with params being the following:

```
int id;
String name, surname, city, street;
java.sql.Date date;
```

This gives me the following exception:

> SQL Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1

Why aren't the values set in the st.setXXXX statements?

Thanks

Comment: replace st.executeUpdate(insert); with st.executeUpdate();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
st.executeUpdate(insert);
```

So, instead of [PreparedStatement.executeUpdate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) you call [Statement.executeUpdate(String sql)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) and pass insert statement with question marks.

Try to change this line to:

```
st.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with SQL syntax. I suspect the semicolon at the end of the SQL statement. It does not belong there - you probably copied it form some other tool where you tested your query.